# gulp-autoprefixer не устанавливает префиксы

Tags: css, css3, gulp

gulp-autoprefixer не устанавливает префиксы

Если я в пишу сss

```
a {
    display: flex;
}
```

то все нормально, устанавливает префиксы

а если так:

```
.border_radius {
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

то не устанавливает префиксы. Но я же точно помню, что они там должны быть.

```
//autoprefixer
gulp.task('autoprefixer', function () {
    return gulp.src('src/css/**/*.css')
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 16 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/autoprefixer'));
});
```

Comment: Что-то у вас не так со средой сборки. Специально проверил, для `last 16 versions` gulp-autoprefixer@3.1.0 добавляет `-webkit-border-radius`.

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev - а , спасибо. Я просто не обновил gulp watch Все работает

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще, на гитхабе самого автопрефикса написано, что по умолчанию он не ставит устаревшие префиксы

https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer

И действительно, префикс -webkit- для border-box ставится только для Safari/Chrome 4, действительно ли вас беспокоят эти браузеры?
http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius

И не думаете ли вы, что поставив значение "last 16 versions", ваш CSS будет кроссбраузерным?)

Comment: И не думаете ли вы, что поставив значение "last 16 versions", ваш CSS будет кроссбраузерным?) - а почему нет?

Comment: Потому что, к примеру, автопрефиксер вам не поможет объяснить для IE 7-, что вы хотите, когда пишете display: inline-block для какого-нибудь блочного элемента)

Comment: ну это да. А почему - ваш CSS не будет кроссбраузерным ----- для актуальных версий браузеров будет же работать ? Спасибо.

Comment: тут смотря что считать актуальными версиями браузеров. думаю, сами понимаете - зависит от того, кто платит)

Answer (score -1):

Поставьте "last 16 versions" и все будет отлично

Comment: Прочитайте внимательней вопрос. Это уже используется.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?